# Why does my Angular project doesnt write data in the firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm developing an angular project for my technical degree, and i've tried to do the write in DB procedure based on this Article: https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-a-crud-firebase-documents-in-angular/

First of all, in the teacher.component.html, i added the formsGroup from @angular/forms in my inputs just like the Article, but i addapted the values to my project, like this code:

```
<form [formGroup]="this.form">
      <div class="right">
      <div>
      <input mat-input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" formControlName="Username" autocomplete="off">
      </div>
      <div>
      <input mat-input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" formControlName="email" autocomplete="on">
      </div>
      <div>
        <input mat-input type="tel" name="wpp" placeholder="wpp" formControlName="wpp" autocomplete="on">
      </div>
      <div>
        <textarea name="bio" id="bio" placeholder="Write your bio" formControlName="bio" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input mat-input type="number" min="1" step="any"name="perhour" placeholder="perhour" formControlName="perhour" autocomplete="on">
      </div>
      <div class="buttons">
        <button mat-button (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

In the `teacher.component.js` i've created this variable inside the class Teacher

```
form = new FormGroup({
      Username: new FormControl(''),
      email: new FormControl(''),
      wpp: new FormControl(''),
      bio: new FormControl(''),
      perhour: new FormControl(''),
      completed: new FormControl(false)
      //new: new FormControl(''),
  })
```

i've also created the method `onSubmit()` to send the data to the firestore database:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.firestore.collection('Teacher').add({
      field: this.form
        //field: this.form.value.new,
    })
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.form.reset();
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    })
}
```

And finnaly in the method `onInit()` i´ve inserted this functions:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.firestore.collection('Teacher').add({field:this.form})
    
  }
```

Just like the title says, i tried to insert a data through the form in the table of the firebase, and dont had writed anything, if someone could help me, with constructive critics and good apointments, i thank so much.

Sorry if i dont writed the text well, this is my first time writing a post here.

Comment: why are u adding data to firestore in `ngOnInit`? It is a lifecycle method that will be called after Angular has initialized all data-bound properties of a directive. Inside `onSubmit` do `console.log(this.form)`

Answer (score 0):

Delete the method call in `ngOnInit` because it will always add a empty form

```
this.firestore.collection('Teacher').add({field:this.form}).
```

Only leave the code `onSubmit()` I think will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

*My answer´s consider you´re using Firestore, not Firebase, it´s different products. The link tou posted is a little odd, it has the Firebase on photo, but appears to using firestore on it.*

It´s may not your problem, but this line is not correct:

```
<form [formGroup]="this.form">
```

Use this way instead:

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
```

The way you code is implemented, you´ll have on you collection the form object instead of it´s values, inside one field called 'field'

To save the form values, just do:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.firestore.collection('Teacher').add({...this.form.value})
    .then(res => { // res here, is the document reference;
        this.firestore.collection('Teacher').doc(res.id).update({id: res.id}); // Do this to keep the id in the document, it´s usefull to further edition. 
        console.log(res);
        this.form.reset();
    })
    .catch(e => {
        console.log(e);
    })
}
```

This way, you´ll have a document with properties containing the same names of your form. Then, when you need to edit it, you can just do a patch value to the form, ie:

```
this.firestore.collection('Teacher').doc(id).valueChanges.pipe( 
  map(values => {
    this.form.patchValue(values)
  })
)
```

Comment: I've deleted the this in the html, and also edited the onSubmit, and this bugs apeared:
Cannot find name 'form'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.form'?ts(2663)
Cannot find name 'docRef'.ts(2304)
I dont know if i did something wrong or something else.

Comment: @RicardoBorges sorry man, I´d editted the code the correct is `this.form.value` and `res.id`instead of `docRef.id`.